# Momentum Increase Limit in Black Hole Case

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

During gravitational collapse of larger stars the compression of matter will make the position of fundamental particles more precise. This is bound to increase their momentum. My question is does the momentum space replace the position space (more or less) exactly so that the momentum vectors cover the area that was previously atomic structure?

I realize that "black holes" formed this way are considerably smaller than the stars they replace but a lot of matter has been blown off in supernova. Can a non-primordial "black hole" interior be composed of mass x velocity without any actual position?

Comment: The Schwarzschield singularity is not a line.